# Laravel database connection error while running migrations

Tags: laravel

I am developing my project in laravel v4.2 everything is working fine but when I run migrations then I receive following error all the time

> [InvalidArgumentException]    Database [] not configured.

Below is my database configurations

```
'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(
        'sqlite' => array(
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => __DIR__ . '/../database/production.sqlite',
            'prefix' => '',
        ),
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'fivestart_db',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'port' => 3306,
        ),
        'pgsql' => array(
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'forge',
            'username' => 'forge',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ),
        'sqlsrv' => array(
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'database',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'prefix' => '',
        ),
    ),
```

even all the other project is working fine with no database configurations issue.

I don't know that what is wrong with the code?

Comment: The configuration you are showing is ok.Is it possible there is a database call you are using specifying a "Database" connection you have not configured? Look for this: "DB::connection('Database')" in your code.

Comment: It can be the cache. You can perform a `php artisan config:clear` to clear the cache or `php artisan config:cache` to clear and store the config in the cache.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your `.env` file:

```
APP_DB=mysql
```

and this to your `config/database.php` file

```
'default' => env('APP_DB','mysql'),
```

This way the app knows which database connection configuration must be used (mysql, in your case)